# Как получить предыдущий месяц, массив дней и год?

Tags: javascript

Как получить тоже самое, но с предыдущем месяцем?

1. Массив дней предыдущего месяца
2. Предыдуший месяц
3. Предыдущий год,если предыдуший месяц будет декабрь

Ниже это на текущий месяц

```js
let days = new Date((new Date).getFullYear(), (new Date).getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
days = Array.from({length:days}, (_, i) => i + 1);

let month = ('0'+ ((new Date).getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
let year = (new Date).getFullYear();

console.log(days, month, year);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let month = ((new Date).getMonth() - 1) < 0 ? 11 : (new Date).getMonth() - 1;
let year = (month == 11) ? (new Date).getFullYear() - 1 : (new Date).getFullYear();
let days = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();
days = Array.from({length:days}, (_, i) => i + 1);
month++;

console.log(days, month, year);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date(Date.now());
var PreviosMonth = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() -1)); 

let days = new Date(PreviosMonth.getFullYear(), PreviosMonth.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
days = Array.from({length:days}, (_, i) => i + 1);

let month = ('0'+ (PreviosMonth.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
let year = PreviosMonth.getFullYear();
```